# Network loss stalls where it should fall to zero quickly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a neural network with 30 input nodes, 1 hidden node, and 1 output node. I am training it on a dataset where the inputs are 30-dimensional vectors with entries between -1 and 1, and the targets are the 2nd entry of these vectors.

I expect the network to train and learn to output the 2nd entry of the input vector quickly, since this is as simple as decreasing the weights in the network which connect the input nodes to the hidden node to zero except the one for the 2nd entry.

However, The loss stalls quickly at approximately 0.168. I'ld expect it to quickly go to zero, which is the case if the targets are just 0.

The following code showcases the problem with a randomised dataset.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
np.random.seed(123)
dataSize = 100000
xdata = np.zeros((dataSize, 30))
ydata = np.zeros((dataSize))
for i in range(dataSize):
    vec = (np.random.rand(30) * 2) - 1
    xdata[i] = vec
    ydata[i] = vec[1]
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="relu", input_shape=(30, )))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
lossObject = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossObject)
model.fit(xdata, ydata, epochs=200, batch_size=32)
```

I have tried multiple different optimizers, loss functions, batch sizes, dataset sizes and learning rates, however the result is always the loss stalling at a relatively high value.

Why is this happening? I am not interested in responses asking why I am doing this. I am new to neural networks and I need to understand why this is happening before I can continue with my original task.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your targets are between -1 and 1, but a sigmoid output activation limits outputs to [0, 1], making it impossible to achieve zero loss if any targets happen to be < 0 (which is very likely with a large dataset). You could fix it by using `tanh` as activation instead, which maps to [-1, 1], or just using no activation in the output layer should be fine in this case. When you fix all targets to 0, this is obviously not an issue, and (almost) zero loss can be achieved.

As a general lesson: Always make sure your output activation makes sense with regards to your target data. At the very least, the value ranges should be identical -- although this might not be a *sufficient* condition for a good output activation.

As a second point: Having a single node with `relu` activation is also a bad idea. If the input to relu is < 0, the output will be 0, and the gradient will be, as well. In this case, no learning is possible and incorrect outputs for some data points may never be corrected.
It is generally not a problem if *some* units are 0 *some* of the time because the gradient can flow through other paths, but with only one unit, this will likely cripple learning as well. I would recommend that you either use more units in the hidden layer, or use a different activation function.

Comment: Thank you! I was so obsessed with finding more complicated reasons why this was not working that I did not see the most obvious solution! I really appreciate the extra information too, I am trying to teach myself these things and its surprisingly difficult to learn some of these basic lessons which are obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Well it's a good thing you are trying to understand these concepts with simple examples! Too many people jump straight to some complex "popular" task without really knowing what they're doing...